# Using relative sizes with rem units in Sapper

Tags: css, svelte, sapper

I am using Sapper to create a web app and want to use relative font sizes.

I have set fixed font sizes for different media queries on the `body` element. Then I want to use `rem` units for the `font-size` in subsequent text elements of Svelte components to adjust the font-size to the viewport.

HTML (Svelte component)

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

CSS (of the Svelte component)

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Global CSS of Sapper

```
body {
  font-size: 12 px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px ) {
  body {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

I would expect that the local component CSS is able to read the font-size on the global `body` element and therefore adjust the font-size in `h1` to the viewport size. However, no action is seen. In contrast, using `em` units works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Svelte to not remove unused CSS selectors you can use the [`:global`](https://svelte.dev/docs#style) modifier.

To change the font size used by `rem` values you should style `html`, not `body`.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/756e6750f6eb4b9dbd377f382985cb0c?version=3.5.4))**

```html
<h1>Hello!</h1>

<style>
  :global(html) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    :global(html) {
      font-size: 15px;
    }
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Great, it's the `html` I have to style not the `body`, that was the bug. It actually works without the `:global`, when I include it in the `global.css` of Sapper. Thanks!